# How to collect thread dumps on ant timeout?

Tags: java, multithreading, ant

We are running our automated integration test suites using ant's `<java>` task, with a timeout (for situations like deadlocks, hanging tests etc.).

```
<java jar=..... fork="true" timeout="100000ms"/>
```

The problem is one of our suites is hanging randomly once in a while (on a Linux VM).

How can I take a thread dump of the forked process at the moment of the timeout-trigerred kill?